# How to automate wifi interface in iphone 5s via python/perl

Tags: iphone

I am trying to include iphone 5s in to my test bed. For which case i have to automate the iphone 5s through usb for wifi connectivity. How i can proceed ahead? If some one has already done the same thing, please help me to give some sample code sothat i can improve further.

Comment: what exactly have you tried and where have you failed or got problems - please show some effort and people will happily try to help you but SO is no place to ask for working code where you haven't shown some effort on your own

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. This is the first time i am working on ios. Really i am not able to access the shell of iphone from my system. Do i need IOS sdk to access the shell of iphone? From the search i couldn't find any clue of it.